# How to include Azure API management API's in azure traffic manager

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-traffic-manager

I wanted to manage API's published in the Azure API management to be included in the traffic manager for high availability. But when I choose external endpoint option and included API management API hostname it is showing invalid host name.

https://xxxxx.azure-api.net like this domain name have placed

Answer (score 1):

If you have two DNS names that can be used as a active/active or active/passive for your API endpoints, you can add them to a Traffic Manager profile and set the routing method you want to use. As indicated in an earlier answer, use only the DNS name and not the protocol identifier (http/https) when you add an endpoint to a Traffic manager profile

Answer (score 0):

Traffic manager only wants the DNS name (FQDN) for external endpoints not the protocol.  So drop the http: or https: from your API management address and it will accept that as an external endpoint.

Or is your problem not with adding the endpoint, but with the health endpoint monitoring?   That can happen as the endpoint for the API Management gateway will return a 404 by default as it does not have a publicly exposed default page.

Comment: APIM default status endpoint is /status-0123456789abcdef If your service has external dependencies it's easy to create a new API, add it to open product (so that it does not require key to call), and within operation policy ping external endpoints via send-request policy. Analyze ping results and use return-response to produce desired status code.

Comment: can you explain how to have traffic manager in front of API management. I'm not getting any posts on how to configure regarding this.

Comment: If you have two DNS names that can be used as a active/active or active/passive for your API endpoints, you can add them to a Traffic Manager profile and set the routing method you want to use.

Comment: If you have two DNS names that can be used as a active/active or active/passive for your API endpoints, you can add them to a Traffic Manager profile and set the routing method you want to use.